# What is the UUID of my swap drive?

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, ssd, swap, uuid

I'm dual-booting Ubuntu 13.10 on an ASUS Windows 8 with an SSD (but not on the SSD).

I configured it when installing to use a swap drive, but it doesn't seem to be using it since I get this message on the load screen:

```
could not mount /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 M for manual S for skip
```

And my linux OS keeps crashing.

### Here's my question:

I can see two different UUID's for my swap drive:

one from `sudo blkid | grep swap`:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="a08247f7-a5d9-4d5a-bde7-41339a41ed42" TYPE="swap"
```

and one from `sudo nano /etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=1507d33a-9aed-4091-8d5f-b0d27434f9fc /               ext4    errors=remoun$
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C61B-97CB  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
# UUID=375639c1-f7b0-4428-a47f-7fdae8f899eb none            swap    sw           $
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

I'm wondering **should I change the UUID in fstab to the one that I get from `blkid`**?  Also, I can see the same UUID when I search `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`.

**Would it be a problem for me to try changing the swap UUID in fstab (and uncomment), or am I wrong in assuming that I should, or is there a more proper way to fix this problem?**

### Output of `free`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       5995912    5030668     965244          0      15588    1169388
-/+ buffers/cache:    3845692    2150220
Swap:      8000508     124356    7876152
```

Comment: tip, to see if you're using swap, use the `free` command, it will show a "Swap" line, if that shows 0 then indeed it's not being used.

Comment: @roadmr Updated with output from `free`.  Doesn't appear to be 0.  But why would it be commented out in `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 1):

```
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
# UUID=375639c1-f7b0-4428-a47f-7fdae8f899eb none            swap    sw           $
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

My guess is that initially swap is created here, but then the partition gets formatted as cryptswap, so instead of using the raw partition and the UUID, it relies on /dev/mapper (which is why the UUID line is commented out).

For reference, on my system the UUIDs are also different, but cryptswap1 is correctly mounted.

cryptswap is configured in `/etc/crypttab`, should contain something like this for your system (note that fstab says that your swap was originally on /dev/sda9):

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sda9 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

If the partitions have been relocated somehow and /dev/sda9 no longer exists, you probably need to update crypttab to reflect the new location.

You can find more information on how to set up and diagnose cryptswaps here:

http://hydra.geht.net/tino/howto/linux/cryptswap/

Comment: My /etc/cryptab says the same thing.  Do you get the could not mount message on the load screen? @roadmr

Comment: Hi! no, sorry, my crypttab mounts correctly :( so I'm not entirely sure what could be wrong with yours.